# Use T as a type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a sqlite class with a few entities and I don't want to create a method for every type of entity like this:

```
public async List<Sheep> GetSheeps()
{
    return database.Table<Sheep>().ToListAsync();
}

public async List<Goat> GetGoats()
{
    return database.Table<Goat>().ToListAsync();
}
```

I want to create an interface (e.g. `IEntity`) and inherit it my POCO classes of sheep and goat.
Then I want to create just one generic method to get the items.

This is what I tried, it says I cannot use `T` as a type:

```
public async T GetEntities<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == IEntity)
        return database.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Maybe I dind't completely understand what `T` is..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `class Goat: IEntity { }` and `class Sheep: IEntity { }`, and then all other classes inherit either `Goat` or `Sheep`?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is going on without seeing all your class definitions.  Can you [edit] your post to include a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your situation exactly?

Comment: I want to inherit IEntity to Goat and Sheep just to verify that it's a valid type to get from the generic method, that something like e.g. GetEntities<int>() cannot be called, just Goat and Sheep. Because only Goat and Sheep are entities of the sqlite database, other types make no sense and will maybe throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly...

- You will want to `await` an `async` call
- Since you are using an `async` `await` pattern, you will need to return a `Task`
- Since you want to return a list of `T` you will have to declare the `List<T>` as a generic parameter of your task i.e `Task<List<T>>`
- Instead of checking for the type `typeof(T) == IEntity` use a constraint `where T : IEntity`

**Code**

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetEntities<T>() where T : IEntity
{
    return await database.Table<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Though, some things to consider

- All your classes will have to inherit from `IEntity`
- It's best to use the `using` statement when dealing with a db (and not hold a reference to it)
- This smells like a repository and you are not really saving much code. *EF* and ORMS are already a repository pattern and unit of work

**Using**

```
var myLovelyHorseList = await GetEntities<Horse>();
```

**Update**

Its a bit early in the morning for me and i am with out a coffee and cant test this. but i think you might need the `new()` constraint, and your classes will have to have a parametesless constructor

```
where T : IEntity, new()
```

[new Constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that, but it says: "T has to be a non-abstract type with a public, parameterless constructor to be able to be used as a T-parameter in the generic method SQLiteAsyncConnection.Table<T>()"

Comment: `GetEntities<T>() where T: class` will get you `sheep` and `goat` presuming they are public and have parameterless constructors

Comment: as @TheGeneral pointed out, you may be making things harder than need be.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven This makes it easier for me, bacause when I have a lot of entities I don't need to code a bunch of one-line-methods for the add edit delete stuff.
TheGeneral Thank you very much, it works! And I learned something about constraints :)